# Modifying Android kernel swap

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

If I were to modify the swap mechanism in an android kernel that has the swap feature, what specific location of the kernel should I check?

Comment: What do you mean by modify ? If you want to disable it completely, you can recompile kernel with CONFIG_SWAP commented.

Comment: To modify the operation of the memory swapping present in the kernel. Is it possible to do some modifications in the default memory swapping operation of the kernel (ex. limiting a certain application to be swapped out of the RAM)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification, for preventing certain memory from being swapped out of RAM, you can use [mlock()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock).

Comment: I see, is there a way on determining applications involved in the memory space being locked? Another question I'd like to ask is, is it possible to execute this commands on an application for android (not touching the kernel code)?

Comment: The address passed to mlock() is the virtual address of an application. So you are pinning physical pages allocated to passed virtual memory address. Sorry, I do not know about android.